# CALayer BlendMode

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, ipod

I am creating a simple iOS application in which I have two CALayers, I want to add the blend effect on the upper CALayer to display the content on the second layer. I dont want to do it alpha. Is there any way to do this without changing the alpha?

Answer (score 6):

iOS (as of 5.1) does not currently support any blend effects on `CALayer`.  In my testing, the `compositingFilter` property is ignored.

Answer (score 2):

There's a tricky way to achieve this.

`compositingFilter` works but filter names should be like `subtractBlendMode` (lower camel case), not `CISubtractBlendMode`.

Here is a demo:

https://github.com/arthurschiller/CompositingFilters

Answer (score 0):

Use property

> **opacity**

of CALayer as there is nothing such as alpha. Its opacity instead of alpha
so try setting opacity of the layers.